# Returning multiple values from multiple drop-downs in Powershell

Tags: powershell, dropdown

I am a very new to powershell. I was tasked with creating a GUI that takes in several strings from multiple drop-downs and renames the computer according to those choices. I am testing it with two options, $FacilityInitials and $BuildingNumber. Powershell is returning only the $BuildingNumber choice.

I may be doing something wrong with returning? How should I do multiple return fuctions properly? Thank you! :)

I tried checking for typos.

```
#Edit This item to change the DropDown Values

[array]$DropDownArray1 = "LI", "BE", "HA"

# This Function Returns the Selected Value and Closes the Form

function Return-DropDown {
$script:Choice = $DropDown1.SelectedItem.ToString()
$Form.Close()
}

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")


$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$Form.width = 350
$Form.height = 200
$Form.Text = ”Computer Renamer”

$DropDown1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,30)
$DropDown1.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)

ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray1) {
[void] $DropDown1.Items.Add($Item)
}

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDown1)

$DropDown1Label = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDown1Label.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,30) 
$DropDown1Label.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20) 
$DropDown1Label.Text = "Facility Initials:"
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDown1Label)

################################################################################

#Edit This item to change the DropDown Values

[array]$DropDownArray2 = "01", "02", "03"

# This Function Returns the Selected Value and Closes the Form

function Return-DropDown {
$script:Choice2 = $DropDown2.SelectedItem.ToString()
$Form.Close()
}

$DropDown2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,60)
$DropDown2.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)

ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray2) {
[void] $DropDown2.Items.Add($Item)
}

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDown2)

$DropDown2Label = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDown2Label.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,60) 
$DropDown2Label.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20) 
$DropDown2Label.Text = "Building Number:"
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDown2Label)

################################################################################

#Button

$Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,130)
$Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$Button.Text = "Rename Computer"
$Button.Add_Click({Return-DropDown})
$form.Controls.Add($Button)

################################################################################


$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()

$FacilityInitials = $Choice
$BuildingNumber = $Choice2

$newCompName = $FacilityInitials + "-" + $BuildingNumber

$AdminAcc = ""

#Add Restart and Force later

Rename-Computer -NewName $newCompName -DomainCredential $AdminAcc
```

Comment: `ComboBox` doesn't support multiple selections, use a `ListBox` with it's [`SelectionMode` set to `MultiExtended`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectionmode?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: If this is a new project, I advise using WPF.  It'll be easier to maintain and has an interactive editor that will give you the xml definition through Visual Studio.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you! Successfully implemented a `ListBox` based GUI.